# How to point external directory of images on tomcat servers port number 8888?

Tags: java, tomcat7

I am new to tomcat administration.
I have a some set of images that is located in `C:` drive of my *VPN* but outsude the tomcat server.

I have web application that is works fine on Tomcats 8080 port.

Now I want to port above images folder to 8888 port.

So if some one loads url like (`localhost:8888/images/`) he will get all images here.

And load url `localhost:8080/MyServerApplication/` will get my web application.

Comment: You can define two different HTTP `Connector`s on different ports but I'm not sure you can redirect seperate Web apps to different ports.

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> <Context docBase="C:/actualimagepath/" path="/images" privileged="true"></Context>
I wrote above xml in localhost folder of Catalina
and if I call URL localhost:8888/images/imageurl
this will show url from actual image folder.
This works fine.

But I want these image from URL localhost:8888/imageurl.

What change i need to show images.

Comment: why don't you change the path to the root path (`path="/"`)?

Answer (score 0):

This is the most convoluted way of doing this. Ideally you should use a Reverse Proxy to serve static content and proxy the webapp. So you can have static.mysite.com point to your images and www.mysite.com point to your Tomcat.

However if you really, really want to do it the other way around, you need to:

1. Add a new  block to your server.xml, which defines the image service, listening on port 8888.
2. Create an images.war web application, containing only the static images.
3. Deploy the webapp to your new service.

Comment: Actually I want to use these images in my webapp.
where I have image name stored in my database.
And I prefix www.myapp.com:8888 in code to show these images.
where my app runs on www.myapp.com:8080 port.

This is because of even if I changed on different server I do not need to change code.

Comment: Yes. This does not change the answer. However there are two significant flaws in your design. Since you are hard coding the site baseurl you will need to change the code, or change everything else. The second flaw is that most corporate firewalls will block any ports other than port 80 by default.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just link a folder inside webapps to the folder in C: ??

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using apache 24.
where I point my images folder in httpd.conf file.